# Convert hstore column to a XPO class property Npgsql 3.2.7

Tags: npgsql

We have upgraded Npgsql from 2.2.5 to 3.2.7.

We have a database column of type hstore.

In 2.2.5 
this column used to be converted by a XPO valueconverter 
from a string that came from the database 
to a List < Tuple< object, object>> that we wanted in a XPO class.

Before 3.2.7 something has changed
and when we try to read this column,
we get an error stating that "an object should implement IConvertible".
But it does not state, which object should be IConvertible. 
I presume that this is the target XPO property, 
of type List< Tuple< object,object>>

We have tried to change the property to IConvertible but without effect.

Has anybody had similar problems with the hstore type and the 3.* upgrade?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea exactly what your application does (or how XPO works), but Npgsql 3.x returns PostgreSQL hstore as `Dictionary<string,string>`. It seems like your client code (XPO?) may be expecting the value returned by Npgsql to be IConvertible, which isn't the case anymore.

Comment: I have already solved the case for complex types.

I have a complex database type my_complex_type that has properties: a,b,c.
I have an XPO class with a property of type: XPMyComplexType with properties: A,B,C.

After npgsql upgrade, I was forced to make XPMyComplexType IConvertible.
I have implemented ToString() method and it returns $"({a},{b},{c})" //produces: (a,b,c)
which is exactly the string that is read from the database.

And this has solved the case for complex types.

Comment: Now, I think that if I could only change the property that is populated with hstore data
to some type that inherits from Dictionary< string,string>
and make it IConvertible
by finding the right implementation of ToString() method,
I would solve the problem.

Am I right?
Could you give me some hint on how the method should look like for hstore data?

Comment: I have no idea who exactly is requiring the types to implement IConvertible, but it's definitely not coming from Npgsql. You could certainly subclass `Dictionary<string,string>`, but I don't see how that would help since Npgsql itself returns `Dictionary<string,string>`, and not your subclass... Try to understand exactly what's going on and how to have your code work well with non-IConvertible types.

Comment: OK, I got it. The change of the type read from the database from string to Dictionary<string,string> has causes errors in XPO that does not handle it properly. Just in case somebody  else encounters this issue: One needs to subclass PostgreSqlConnectionProvider and override the ReformatReadVaue() method to omit Dictionary<string,string>. Second thing is a proper value converter for the property. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T614674/problem-with-hstore-fields-after-upgrading-from-16-2-to-17-2  Thank you again for pointing me at the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I got it. The change of the type read from the database from string to Dictionary has caused errors in XPO that does not handle it properly. Just in case somebody  else encounters this issue: One needs to subclass PostgreSqlConnectionProvider and override the ReformatReadVaue() method to omit Dictionary. Second thing is a proper value converter for the property. https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T614674/problem-with-hstore-fields-after-upgrading-from-16-2-to-17-2

Thank you again for pointing me at the right direction.